# How to print thread code in command prompt

Tags: c#

what is this called "the thread 0x2ef0" and how can I display it in the command prompt? I tried executing the code and it was only display in the output box or the debugger code, is there a possible way to print this hex decimal thread code? to the command prompt? i was using an windows application with windows property but when i tried in windows application with console property the "the thread 0x2ef0" is not showing off so i want to display it in command prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one of these:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x4}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x4}", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
            Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x4}", AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
            Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x4}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [CurrentThread property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentthread?view=net-6.0) in order to get the data you are looking for.

```
Task<Double> t = Task.Run( () => { ShowThreadInformation("Main Task(Task #" + Task.CurrentId.ToString() + ")");
                                     for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 20; ctr++)
                                       tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                          () => { ShowThreadInformation("Task #" + Task.CurrentId.ToString());
                                                  long s = 0;
                                                  for (int n = 0; n <= 999999; n++) {
                                                     lock (rndLock) {
                                                        s += rnd.Next(1, 1000001);
                                                     }
                                                  }
                                                  return s/1000000.0;
                                                } ));

                                    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                                    Double grandTotal = 0;
                                    Console.WriteLine("Means of each task: ");
                                    foreach (var child in tasks) {
                                       Console.WriteLine("   {0}", child.Result);
                                       grandTotal += child.Result;
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    return grandTotal / 20;
                               } );
  Console.WriteLine("Mean of Means: {0}", t.Result);
```